# Compute area of rooftops in map images

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm an R user having trouble with image analysis in Python. What's an efficient way to compute the area of a building at the center in the image? The goal is to apply an edge algorithm to a Google Maps static image and compute the surface area of the rooftop of an address.

```python
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
import urllib
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import filter, io, measure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def getMap(address):
    """Geocode address and retreive image centered
    around lat/long"""

    results = Geocoder.geocode(address)
    lat, lng = results[0].coordinates
    zip_code = results[0].postal_code

    map_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={0},{1}&size=640x640&zoom=19&sensor=false&maptype=roadmap&&style=visibility:simplified|gamma:0.1'
    request_url = map_url.format(lat, lng)
    req = urllib.urlopen(request_url)
    return(req)

def mapEdge(req):
    """Convert img to bytearray and do edge detection
    on centered building"""

    img = io.imread(req.geturl(),flatten=True)
    labels, numobjects = ndimage.label(img)
    edges = filter.canny(img, sigma=3)
    plt.imshow(edges, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.show()

map_tmp = getMap('1403 Elmwood Ave., Evanston, IL')
mapEdge(map_tmp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to proceed would be to use contour finding technique available in opencv and then detect the center of the contour. The code is in c++ but can be very easily be converted into python

```
    findContours( dst4, contours2, hierarchy2, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly2( contours2.size() );
    vector<Rect> boundRect2( contours2.size() );
    cout << contours2.size()<<endl;
    Mat drawing1=Mat::zeros(dst4.rows,dst4.cols,dst4.depth());
    for( int i = 0; i < contours2.size(); i++ ){
        approxPolyDP( Mat(contours2[i]), contours_poly2[i], 3, true );
        boundRect2[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly2[i]) );
    }
```

Now that you have a vector of bounding rectangle and thus if the center of the bounding rectangle is very close to the center of your image then its a positive match.

Here is a tutorial for contour finding using python
http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would look at one of those libraries:

- scikit-image
- OpenCV
- SimpleCV ([example with blobs](http://help.simplecv.org/question/500/finding-blob-areas/))